# Matlab signal implementation

Tags: matlab, signals, signal-processing

I am trying to implement the following system in MATLAB.
I am reading an audio signal and want to perform the operation below.

[image]

so far I have done the following:

```
%read the audio file
[y,Fs] = audioread('input_original.wav');

syms k x
yx = symsum(k, k, -inf, y);

%write the output
audiowrite('signal_divbb.wav',yx,Fs,'BitsPerSample',64)
```

is there a way to implement this signal properly? I am not familiar with MATLAB

Comment: Since it is already answered I just want to point out here, the difference between the theory and implementation is that you cannot talk about `inf` of a finite-time signal, which is recorded and stored on the disk as a finite-sized file.

Comment: so the value at n will be the running sum from index 1 until n?

Comment: Assuming the first index as `-Inf`, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output of `audioread` (your `y` variable) has `m` rows times `n` columns, where `m` is the signal length and `n` is the number of channels (2 for stereo). You can use [`cumsum`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html) as follows:

```
yx = cumsum(y, 1);
```

This computes the cumulative sum along the first dimension (i.e. time). So `yx(k,c)` equals `y(1,c)+y(2,c)+...+y(k,c)`, where `k` ranges from from `1` to `m`, and `c` is the channel index from `1` to `n`.